# How to exclude files from Projectile?

Tags: projectile

I am using the helm-projectile setup from prelude and it has been a huge improvement to my workflow. The only remaining issue are auto-generated files (e.g. generated by CMake) which show up during helm-grep and similar operations.

**Question**: is there a way to exclude files in the projects folder tree from Projectile?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Looking at projectile it seems to offer four customizations for ignoring
files/directories globally. I am listing each of them below, with their
documentation

`projectile-globally-ignored-files`

> A list of files globally ignored by projectile.

`projectile-globally-ignored-directories`

> A list of directories globally ignored by projectile.

`projectile-globally-ignored-file-suffixes`

> A list of file suffixes globally ignored by projectile.

`projectile-globally-ignored-modes`

> A list of regular expressions for major modes ignored by projectile.
>
> If a buffer is using a given major mode, projectile will ignore
>   it for functions working with buffers.

Please note that these are global options so for example a directory in
`projectile-globally-ignored-directories` will be ignored irrespective of the
project you are working with. To ignore a file/directory for a particular
project you can add a `.projectile` file to the project's root and add
the paths to ignore prefixed with `-` to it like following

```
-/CMake
```

See the documentation of `projectile-parse-dirconfig-file` (or [projectile's docs](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/doc/usage.md#ignoring-files)) for more info

> Parse project ignore file and return directories to ignore and keep.
>
> The return value will be a cons, the car being the list of
>   directories to keep, and the cdr being the list of files or
>   directories to ignore.
>
> Strings **starting with +** will be added to the list of 
>   **directories
>   to keep**, and strings **starting with -** will be added to the list of
>   **directories to ignore**.  For backward compatibility, **without a**
>   **prefix** the string will be **assumed to be an ignore string**.

Comment: I'm unable to get ``projectile-globally-ignored-file-suffixes`` to work as (I think) it is intended.  Should this contain just the suffix (i.e. "o" for object files), a file glob (i.e. "*.o") or something else?  Frankly I've tried every combo I can think of and it hasn't worked.

Comment: I am using Scala with ensime, and projectile already defines .ensime_cache as globally ignored. However C-c p h brings up helm-projectile and shows all the .ensime_cache files. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bklyn: It is a list of just the suffix (e.g. `(setq projectile-globally-ignored-file-suffixes '("o"))`). You need to purge the cache after changing the setting though (`M-x projectile-invalidate-cache`).

Comment: @ShouYa `(setq projectile-globally-ignored-file-suffixes '("S" "elf" "o" "d" "tex"))` This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not working if you use the indexing method `alien`, default for linux and mac. See an alternative solution from me below.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, in your `.projectile` file, on each line specify similar to:
each line looks like:

```
- /path/to/somefile
```

Each line contains one file path.

See the [official documentation on ignoring files](https://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/#ignoring-files)

Answer (score 9):

Another solution would be to use `ag`([the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)) or `rg` ([ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)) to generate project files. Here's how you can do it with `rg`:

```
(setq projectile-enable-caching t)

;;; Default rg arguments
  ;; https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep
  (when (executable-find "rg")
    (progn
      (defconst modi/rg-arguments
        `("--line-number"                     ; line numbers
          "--smart-case"
          "--follow"                          ; follow symlinks
          "--mmap")                           ; apply memory map optimization when possible
        "Default rg arguments used in the functions in `projectile' package.")

      (defun modi/advice-projectile-use-rg ()
        "Always use `rg' for getting a list of all files in the project."
        (mapconcat 'identity
                   (append '("\\rg") ; used unaliased version of `rg': \rg
                           modi/rg-arguments
                           '("--null" ; output null separated results,
                             "--files")) ; get file names matching the regex '' (all files)
                   " "))

      (advice-add 'projectile-get-ext-command :override #'modi/advice-projectile-use-rg)))
```

In your project directory, specify the files you want to ignore in `.gitignore` and you're good to go :)

Code is from [kaushalmodi's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/115/kaushal-modi) emacs config.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the variable `projectile-indexing-method` is set to `alien`. If that's the case Projectile will ignore ignores/unignores/sorting provided in Projectile config:

> The alien indexing method optimizes to the limit the speed of the
> hybrid indexing method.  This means that Projectile will not do any
> processing of the files returned by the external commands and you’re
> going to get the maximum performance possible.  This behaviour makes a
> lot of sense for most people, as they’d typically be putting ignores
> in their VCS config and won’t care about any additional
> ignores/unignores/sorting that Projectile might also provide.

To solve it change this variable to `native` or `hybrid`.

Comment: More: If native is slow for you, the alternative to get both is to add ignore files and folders in your "projectile-generic-command". I use "rg" (ripgrep) for ultra speed. e.g., add to your default "rg" setup the additional arguments "--glob '!YourFolder1' --glob '!YourFolder2' --ignore-file YourFileToListFilesThatIgnoredGlobally"

Answer (score 4):

search that respects ignored dirs/files:

1. install `ack` (An alternative to grep.  I install via homebrew.)
2. put `--ignore-case` in your `~.ackrc` file (assuming you want to ignore case)
3. bind `helm-projectile-ack` to a key.  I do this in my emacs init via:

```
(use-package helm
  ...
  :bind (...
         ("C-c p s a" . helm-projectile-ack)
        )
  ...
)
```

4. create a `.projectile` file.  E.g.,

```
-.dot
-.jcs
-.svg
-.txt
```

use

```
C-c p s a     ;; search that respects .projectile ignore
```

or

```
C-c s p g     ;; search everything
```

Answer (score 4):

**A new solution with no speed compromise of `projectile`**

Since `projetile-indexing-method` is default set to `alien`, both
`projectile-globally-ignored-directories` and
`projectile-globally-ignored-files` will not be used. However, choosing
`native` indexing method compromises speed performance considerably,
especially for large projects.

Suppose we prefer `alien` for best performance, there is a way to get
both satisfied. The idea is to set `projectile-generic-command` that is
used for `alien` type indexing. Assume we use `ripgrep` (terminal
command `rg`), we can add arguments to `rg` to ignore folders/files as
you prefer,

- ignoring folder by option `--glob` with folders read from
  `projectile-globally-ignored-directories` that you set;
- ignoring files by option `--ignore-file`. However, this option
  specifies a file that lists all files to be ignored. The easy way is
  to create a global file (e.g., in `~/.emacs.d/`) and list there all
  files that you like to put to `projectile-globally-ignored-files`. For
  example, we set a file name `~/.emacs.d/rg_ignore`.

The whole setup as an example is given below:

```lisp
  ;; Due to "alien" indexing method, globally ignore folders/files by
  ;; re-defining "rg" args
  (mapc (lambda (item)
          (add-to-list 'projectile-globally-ignored-directories item))
        '("Backup" "backup" "auto" "archived"))
  ;; files to be ignored should be listed in "~/.emacs.d/rg_ignore"

  ;; Use the faster searcher to handle project files: ripgrep "rg"
  (when (and (not (executable-find "fd"))
             (executable-find "rg"))
    (setq projectile-generic-command
          (let ((rg-cmd ""))
            (dolist (dir projectile-globally-ignored-directories)
              (setq rg-cmd (format "%s --glob '!%s'" rg-cmd dir)))
            (setq rg-ignorefile
                  (concat "--ignore-file" " "
                          (expand-file-name "rg_ignore" user-emacs-directory)))
            (concat "rg -0 --files --color=never --hidden" rg-cmd " " rg-ignorefile))))
```