# disable search in home folder with projectile

Tags: projectile

Sometimes I use dired to navigate in the home folder. If in that moment I press `projectile-find-file`, emacs will freeze and will take about 15 seconds to be ready to use projectile with the home folder.
How can I tell projectile not to search in the home folder, even if I accidentally call `projectile-find-file` when I am in?

Comment: does setting projectile-ignored-projects to include "~/" work?

Comment: I have tried with `(setq projectile-ingnored-projects "~/")` and with `(setq projectile-ignored-projects "macbook")` (macbook is the name of my user and in emacs I see that the current projectile project is names "macbook"), but no luck

Comment: Try (setq projectile-ignored-projects '("path-to-home-dir")). If that doesn't work look at a few suggestions in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16497/how-to-exclude-files-from-projectile.

Answer (score 2):

See a detailed solution in my blog article:
https://oracleyue.github.io/post/fix-issues-projectile/

If you like to quickly see how to exclude files/folder from your projectile-find-file, a short version here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/63744/9262